# How do you bind the checkmarks of submenus in a context menu defined externally?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, contextmenu

In our application we have a central resource where we define all system-wide menus for items.   These menu items are already bound to system-wide-defined commands for our objects.  For instance, anywhere in the app where we are dealing with a 'Foo' object, we simply attach the 'FooContextMenu' resource.  Works great.

BUT... one of the menus defines a submenu representing enumeration values and as such, we want the apropriate menu item to be checked depending on the value of the enum-typed property on the object.  For instance, everywhere in the UI that displays a 'Foo' object, we want to show this context menu...

```
FooContextMenu
    |__First Foo command
    |__Set Foo Encoding
    |   |__EnumValueA
    |   |__EnumValueB
    |   |__EnumValueC // <-- Show checkbox if 'Foo.SomeEnumProp' == 'C'
    |   |__EnumValueD
    |__Other Foo command
    |__Last Foo command
```

Now again, since the commands and context menu resources are defined centrally, they all work to execute the code just fine.  What we can't figure out is how to globally deal with that checkbox.  While we could add the 'ContextMenuOpening' code everywhere, that's the problem.  We have to add that everywhere, but I can't imagine that's how you have to do it.

I'm sure I'm missing something blindingly obvious considering this is basic Windows app (any OS actually) behavior, but I just can't see it. (I'm wondering if the context menus pick up the data context of the item they're attached to and I can do simple bindings, but that's just a guess.) Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContextMenu` behaves a bit differently with regard to the `DataContext`.

```
<ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem Header="Foo" 
                Command="{Binding FooCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

The `DataContext` of the `MenuItem` within the `ContextMenu` will be that of the parent, which is the ViewModel which most likely exposes the collection which the `ListBox.ItemsSource` is bound to in the above example.

If you wanted to work directly with the Model being represented within the listing of items, you would need to use the relative pathing of the given item as seen above in the `CommandParamter` scenario. If you want to simply expose the common command with your ViewModel, then you can use the binding as you are used to as the `DataContext` will be the ViewModel representing the listing of items.

Specific to your example it could look something like this if you were keeping the common behavior within the ViewModel, versus the Model.

```
<ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem Header="Foo">
           <CheckBox 
                 Visibility="{Binding Path=YourProperty, 
                 Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                 My CheckBox
           </CheckBox>
      </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

You could then have your property within your ViewModel call out to a Service where you have everything centralized. If you need the Model to make your decision within the converter, you will need to use the relative pathing to get the `SelectedItem` to pass as a parameter.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'behaves a bit different'.  Doesn't the context menu and its associated menu items just pick up the DataContext of whatever you've attached the context menu to? (In your case it looks like you attached it to the control, but we attach it to a DataTemplate so I believe we already have the item's ViewModel, no RelativeSource needed.) But again, I don't see how that behaves any different than regular binding (unless you're saying it's 'different' because it doesn't pick up the DataContext of the *item* you clicked on, which again makes sense as it wasn't attached there.)

Comment: @MarqueIV Yes, I am referring to the ContextMenu for a selected item and its associated DataContext not being the selected item itself. It's the parent ViewModel, which to me doesn't make sense. If you are not needing the selected item, then it's trivial as mentioned above to bind to your ViewModel.

Comment: But I *do* need the selected item, which is the item you right-click on. (*we have code in the PreviewMouseDown event that auto-selects the item you right-click on, making it the selected item.) Plus, by attaching it to the DataTemplate, you not only get the selected item's DataContext, but it also doesn't show the context menu if you click within the list but not on a list item (e.g. in the area below the items when there's not enough to fill the height.)

Comment: Another question... why are you using AncesorType=ContextMenu and PlacementTarget instead of just doing AncestorType=ListBox?  Then again, your approach seems to work for any Selector-based control. I think I just answered my own question.)  Either way, our menus are meant to work with single items, not selectors, but that's still a damn good thing to know so I'm voting you up.  (If no one else answers, I'll give you the accepted answer too.)

Comment: Actually, I just looked up PlacementTarget.  Not sure that actually has anything to do with the data context so much as the placement of the context menu.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placementtarget.aspx It looks like it more has to do with where the context menua actually appears, meaning you can re-position it based on manually setting this value, but the DataContext is still picked up from what it's actually attached to.

Comment: @MarqueIV PlacementTarget allows you access to the ListBox by way of the ListBox being the relative UIElement when the ContextMenu opens. The ContextMenu exists in a separate VisualTree, hence the behavior where the selected item is not in fact the DataContext of the ContextMenu. If you would like to see other examples and scenarios with regard to the ContextMenu check out http://wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html